# xdebug installed successfully on linux but not working

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

I have installed and configured **Xdebug** on my Linux system, however, I can't see "**Xdebug**" in my **PHPinfo** file despite enabling and when i put the phpinfo source code page in the xdebug wizard , shows me that: **Xdebug installed: no**

Have you any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```
php -v

PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.9.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

---

Also, I added the following lines to the end of the **php.ini** file:

```
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so

xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

---

For the more information about the correct file to edit, i exactly edited this file that the directory is said in the following pic:

[image]

Comment: The command-line PHP and the web-server PHP usually use different configuration files. Look in the output of your phpinfo() to see where the web server is loading its configuration file from, and make sure you edit that one as well.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File : /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini     And i exactly edited this file!

Comment: Have you restarted the web server?

Comment: Of course, I restart it after every edit.

Comment: Make sure you have the xdebug.so include AFTER the opcache include.

Comment: As i said, i included xdebug.so file at the end of the file!

Comment: The path `/opt/lampp` by itself sounds alike a mis-configuration.

Comment: 1) BTW / Side note: You have `with Xdebug v2.9.2` but then using `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` config .. which is **Xdebug v3** (this option will do nothing in v2). 2) What do you have for `php --ini` executed in CLI (terminal)? 3) Please show the whole top table of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser. 4) restart the whole computer/OS (in case if something is not getting applied for some reason) 5) Please also check PHP's error log for possible error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to install xdebug v3 with PHP v7.4 and it doesn't install correctly for my system.

As i see this vide, i update my PHP version to 8 and try it again and my problem was solved now :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHdcx-MwxGs